# Images in DITA-OT

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, dita-ot

I'm creating a publication using DITA and the out of the box DITA-OT pdf2 plugin. The images are not scaling to fit the page, but instead are running huge and being cut off by the page. 
I prefer to keep the out of the box plugin in tact, so I first created a customization folder and modified the custom.xsl file to show:

```
  <fo:external-graphic src="url({$href})" xsl:use-attribute-sets="image">

            <xsl:attribute name="content-width">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(@scale,'%')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>

    </fo:external-graphic>
```

When this didn't work, I tried to modify the xsl/fo/commons.xsl file in the plugin to change

```
    <fo:external-graphic src="url({$href})" xsl:use-attribute-sets="image">

            <xsl:attribute name="content-width">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(@scale,'%')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>

    </fo:external-graphic>
```

This didn't work either. I also tried to hard code the scale-to-fit attribute in the commons.xsl file:

```
    <fo:external-graphic src="url({$href})" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="scale-to-fit">

    </fo:external-graphic>
```

I'm pretty sure somehow the FO is reading height and width still and inserting them, but I can't figure out where I can override the content height and width to scale-to-fit. Any ideas?

Comment: IN which direction are they too large (normally the width)? If its the width, you should have <fo:external-graphic src="url({$href})" content-width="scale-to-fit" width="100%> ...

Comment: Thanks! I was able to put this in the custom.xsl so I didn't mess with the original plugin and can see the difference. Now I need to get the other images to not blow up to stretch across the width. Thanks again!